# Compare performance between Ext.data.JsonReader and Ext.data.ArrayReader

Tags: javascript, extjs

Im using `JsonReader` to load my data, but it seem to low performance with a large data. I want to replace `JsonReader` with `ArrayReader`. I'm sure that the size of data that server response will smaller if I use `ArrayReader`, but not sure if the performance is improved.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not going to get much faster either way. Under the hood, JsonReader simply evals the JSON string straight into an object (and if the browser supports the native `JSON.parse` function, it calls that instead which is even better).  In fact, I would guess that ArrayReader will be slower since it actually iterates over the array to pull the data into records.  Of course you can simply test this out yourself -- changing the reader type is a trivial change.  I'm assuming that you'll have to take a closer look at how much data you are returning from the server.